# how to find maximum value from the sum of Quantity

Tags: sql

Example table Orders

```
+---------+----------+
| OrderID | Quantity |
+---------+----------+
|   10248 |       11 |
|   10248 |       42 |
|   10248 |       72 |
|   10249 |       14 |
|   10249 |       51 |
|   10250 |       41 |
|   10250 |       51 |
+---------+----------+
```

My question is .
How to find the sum of quantity for each orderid and find the highest quantity by a order

```
<select orderid , SUM(quantity) As TotalQty  from order group by orderid
```

result

```
+--------+-----------+
|orderId |  TotalQTY |
+--------+-----------+
|  10248 |       125 |
|  10249 |        65 |
|  10250 |        92 |
+--------+-----------+
```

from the above result i need to display orderid whose total is the highest.

Final result must be

```
+--------+----------+
|orderid | TotalQTY |
+--------+----------+
|  10245 |      125 |
+--------+----------+
```

I need this in a single query

Comment: the final result above i think it should be `10248-- 125`

Answer (score 6):

In MySQL use

```
select orderid, SUM(quantity) As TotalQty
from order 
group by orderid
order by TotalQty desc
limit 1
```

In MSSQL

```
select top 1 orderid, SUM(quantity) As TotalQty
from order 
group by orderid
order by SUM(quantity) desc
```

In Oracle

```
select orderid, SUM(quantity) As TotalQty
from order 
group by orderid
order by SUM(quantity) desc
where ROWNUM <= 1
```

Comment: In oracle i'm getting an error msg syntax error in order by clause

Comment: I updated the answer. Using aliases in the `order by` clause does not work in all DB engines.

Answer (score 2):

In case of SQL-Server, you can use the [`OVER` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
SELECT TOP 1 orderid, SUM(Quantity)OVER(PARTITION BY orderid)AS TotalQTY
FROM dbo.Orders
ORDER BY TotalQTY DESC
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8dfb1/9/0)</kbd>

You can include all columns even if they are not aggregated or part of the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle :

```
select * from (
select orderid, SUM(quantity) As TotalQty
from order
group by orderid
order by TotalQty desc) where rownum =1;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySql:

```
select orderid, SUM(quantity) As TotalQty
from order 
group by orderid
order by TotalQty desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`with cte IN SQL SERVER`

```
;with cte as
(
 select top 1 orderid,sum(TotalQTY) as x from table group by id
 )

 select * from cte
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1);
```